# Use Testcontainers with another Database Driver

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit5, testcontainers, pgjdbc-ng

I am using Testcontainers (https://www.testcontainers.org/) with the Postgres module in a Spring Boot application with Kotlin and have configured everything as in this tutorial (https://www.wwt.com/article/using-testcontainers-for-unit-tests-with-spring-and-kotlin). Additionally I use Liquibase to populate the test container and have also configured the following:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default-schema=public
spring.test.database.replace=none
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/changelog_master.xml
spring.liquibase.contexts=test
logging.level.liquibase=INFO
```

So far everything works, but I want to use the driver from https://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/, because the standard driver from PostgreSQL does not offer the possibility to listen to notifications of database triggers and I want to test this code (https://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-notification) in my integration tests.

For this I changed my application.yml as follows:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver
```

Unfortunately, this leads to the following error message:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase
 /LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
 nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver
 claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://localhost:32840/test?loggerLevel=OFF
```

The problem seems to be that Testcontainers needs the standard driver to create the database from Java. But i wonder how it is possible to change the driver for testing?

**UPDATE 1**
As described in [Mikhail Burshtey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5030758/mikhail-burshteyn) answer, I have overritten the PostgreSQL container class:

```kotlin
class CustomPostgreSQLContainer : PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>("postgres:latest"){

    override fun getJdbcUrl(): String {
        val additionalUrlParams = constructUrlParameters("?", "&")
        return ("jdbc:pgsql://" + containerIpAddress + ":" + getMappedPort(POSTGRESQL_PORT)
            + "/" + databaseName + additionalUrlParams)
    }
    override fun getDriverClassName(): String {
        return "com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver"
    }
}
```

When using this class now I have the problem that the PostgreSQL default driver, which is responsible for creating the container, does not accept the url:

```
Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl,
jdbc:pgsql://localhost:32846/test?loggerLevel=OFF
```

**UPDATE 2**
The actual application (without testcontainers) works. To launch it I use PostgreSQL in a Docker container with:

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name my-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres
```

here is the relevant excerpt from application-dev.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: swagger
    active: dev
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:pgsql://localhost:5432/postgres
    driverClassName: com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver
    username: postgres
    password: password
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 10MB
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
```

**UPDATE 3**
Here is my stacktrace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-28 13:51:52.215 ERROR 29952 --- [    Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:pgsql://localhost:32831/test?loggerLevel=OFF
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1161) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:122) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:105) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:89) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:56) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar:5.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:pgsql://localhost:32831/test?loggerLevel=OFF
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:110) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:325) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:114) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:313) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 109 common frames omitted
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/docs/current/user-guide/), you need to use `jdbc:pgsql` instead of `jdbc:postgresql` in the URL. Maybe you can try to create a subclass of `PostgreSQLContainer.java` and override the [getJdbcUrl()](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/modules/postgresql/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/PostgreSQLContainer.java#L84) method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `postgresql` driver identifier is hardcoded into the JDBC URL which is obtained from the `PostgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl()` method.  See its source code:

```java
    @Override
    public String getJdbcUrl() {
        String additionalUrlParams = constructUrlParameters("?", "&");
        return "jdbc:postgresql://" + getContainerIpAddress() + ":" + getMappedPort(POSTGRESQL_PORT)
            + "/" + databaseName + additionalUrlParams;
    }
```

The driver that you are trying to use expects this value to be `pgsql`, not `postgresql`.

Probably the easiest solution would be to create your own class inheriting from `PostgreSQLContainer` and override `getJdbcUrl`.
Alternatively, you can try to replace the driver in the URL string returned from `getJdbcUrl`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, overwriting does not solve the problem. I made an update in my question.

Comment: Does the actual application work (not the tests with testcontainers)? What configuration are you using there?

Comment: Yes the actual application works with that driver and also the listener for the notifications in the database works as expected (as soon as I add an entry to the database, I get a message in the console). I added an Update to my question with the configuration.

My understanding is that testcontainers needs the default driver to start the database. I have already searched for possibilities to change the driver after the start but could not find anything. I hope you have an idea for my problem.

Comment: Can you attach the stacktrace of the exception that occurs in tests? The one with the message `Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl`

Comment: You could also try overriding `getDriverClassName` in your custom subclass of `PostgreSQLContainer`

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my late response. I have overridden the getDriverClassName method (Update 2) and attached my stacktrace (Update 3). Unfortunately, overwriting didn't change anything.

Comment: @tomson since you use `application-dev.yml` make sure that your test runs with `dev` profile as for now error message states that `org.postgresql.Driver` is still used while you expect `com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver` to be used

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko: You are right! Overwriting the getjdbcurl-Method is definitely enough. I forgot to adjust the driver in my application-test.yaml as well. Thank you for the solution!