# Postgres custom datatypes not working with Testcontainers driver

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, testcontainers

In the integration test, I am trying to save an entry in a table of the `TestContainers` Postgres database using SpringData repository.

But I get the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "status" is of type custom_status but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

This is because the `Proposal` table has a custom type which is an enum. In that case, I am able to save the data successfully when using the real postgres database with postgres driver. But when I am connecting to the `TestContainers` database with `org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver` then I get the error.

How can I handle these custom types when using `TestContainers` in the integration tests?

If I remove the status column from the entity class and sql script then the integration tests work fine with `TestContainers` Postgres database.

GitHub link:- https://github.com/firstpostt/testcontainers

HelloRestControllerTest:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured.given
import io.restassured.http.ContentType
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("it-test")
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 1234)
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@Testcontainers
class HelloRestControllerTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    final val portNumber = 0

    val baseUrl = "http://localhost:$portNumber"

    companion object {
        @Container
        var postgreSQL: PostgreSQLContainer<*> = PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:11.6")

        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun postgreSQLProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.datasource.username") { postgreSQL.username }
            registry.add("spring.datasource.password") { postgreSQL.password }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val helloResponse = given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .get("$baseUrl$portNumber/hello")
            .andReturn()
        println(helloResponse.body)
    }
}
```

application-it-test.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:11.6:///databasename
    hikari:
      max-lifetime: 500000
      connection-timeout: 300000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      maximum-pool-size: 5
      minimum-idle: 1
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: 'classpath:db/migration/postgresql'
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

SQL script:

```
create type custom_status as enum ('STARTED', 'ENDED');

create table proposal (
      proposal_id                           varchar(50),
      amount                                decimal not null ,
      status                                custom_status not null
);
```

Entity:

```
import com.example.demo.CustomStatus
import java.math.BigDecimal
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "proposal")
data class Proposal(

  @Id
  @Column(name = "proposal_id")
  val proposalId: String,

  @Column(name = "amount", nullable = true)
  val amount: BigDecimal?,

  @Column(name = "status")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  val status: CustomStatus

)
```

Enum:

```
enum class CustomStatus(val stringValue: String) {
    STARTED("000"), ENDED("999")
}
```

HelloRestController:

```
import com.example.demo.entity.Proposal
import com.example.demo.repo.ProposalRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.data.repository.findByIdOrNull
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import java.math.BigDecimal

@RestController
class HelloRestController @Autowired constructor(val proposalRepository: ProposalRepository) {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun hello(): ResponseEntity<Proposal>{
        var result = proposalRepository.findByIdOrNull("123")

        if (result == null) {
            result = proposalRepository.save(Proposal("999", BigDecimal.TEN, CustomStatus.STARTED))
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(result)
    }
}
```

Spring data repository class:

```
import com.example.demo.entity.Proposal
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface ProposalRepository : CrudRepository<Proposal, String>
```

application-local.yml which is used for Real database scenario:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/demo?stringtype=unspecified
    username: demo
    password: 'demo'
    hikari:
      max-lifetime: 500000
      connection-timeout: 300000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      maximum-pool-size: 5
      minimum-idle: 1
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: 'classpath:db/migration/postgresql'
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/5824

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354952/use-testcontainers-with-another-database-driver

Comment: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/discussions/5825

Comment: can you remove `driver-class-name: org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver` and `url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:11.6:///databasename`? You already have `PostgreSQLContainer` in `HelloRestControllerTest`. Also, please attach a github repository in order to take a look.

Comment: Follow this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/71935827/2203890 . I tried and worked

Comment: But the code works fine with the real Postgres database already.  I would have to change the code just to make it work with `TestContainers` which doesn't seem like a good approach

Comment: Here is the github link https://github.com/firstpostt/testcontainers

Comment: Hi, I see that `TestContainers` will in-turn use the Postgres driver. So why is the code working with real Postgres driver in real application but the same code not working in integration test with `TestContainers`? That is probably got to do with the `JdbcUrl`. In real application I see that the jdbc url is `url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/demo?stringtype=unspecified`. If I remove `?stringtype=unspecified` then the real application also stops working. So I hope there is a simple fix instead of overriding the `getJdbcUrl` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestContainers` in-turn uses Postgres driver so if real driver works then `TestContainers` should work too. The issue is that you are using additionalParams in your "Real" database url but not using it in test url.

Change the Jdbc Url in your `application-it-test.yml` file as below and it will work:

```
url: jdbc:tc:postgresql:11.6:///databasename?stringtype=unspecified
```

The text `?stringtype=unspecified` is important.

This is used by the `PostgreSQLContainer`. See the decompiled code of `org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer` to see how it is working under the hood:

```
public String getJdbcUrl() {
        String additionalUrlParams = this.constructUrlParameters("?", "&");
        return "jdbc:postgresql://" + this.getHost() + ":" + this.getMappedPort(POSTGRESQL_PORT) + "/" + this.databaseName + additionalUrlParams;
    }
```